# How to find what processes run by the user right now?

Tags: linux, process, ps

I can't find the right command. I want to view the processes that I'm currently running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ps` has `-U` and `-u` options for that.

From `man ps`:

> ```
> -U userlist
> ```
>
> Select by real user ID (RUID) or name.  It selects the processes whose real user name or ID is in the userlist list.
>                 The real user ID identifies the user who created the process, see getuid(2).
>
> ```
> -u userlist
> ```
>
> Select by effective user ID (EUID) or name.  This selects the processes whose effective user name or ID is in
>                 userlist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `top` command to get real time stats of your running processes on Linux System. 
Also you can use `ps -elf` command to get a snapshot of process statistics.